# Why GNOME doesn't unmount a directory that I manually unmounted in the terminal

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, mount

### Background

I'm trying to manually unmount a file system that has been automatically mounted by the system. I don't get any error messages when `umount /dev/user/myusbstick`, but when I go and check the GNOME file manager, the device is still there, still beautifully mounted and easily accessible. Why?

### Steps to reproduce

1. Plug in a USB stick and GNOME lets you know that your device is ready.
2. The file is accessible on GNOME file manager as you expect and mounted under `/media/user/myusbstick`
3. Manually unmount the device now in the terminal:

   ```shell
   umount /media/user/myusbstick
   ```
4. Make sure it's been successfully unmounted.
5. Go back to the GNOME file manager and see that the file system is still accessible.

**The question**: why would it still be accessible on GNOME file manager if I unmounted the file system in the terminal?

Comment: how do you "see that the file system is still accessible", specifically?

Comment: i open the gnome file manager, i can still select the USB device on the left menu, select the folders inside of the usb stick and even edit text documents

Comment: Selecting the USB device automatically mounts it again :)

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhh! I ran the `umont` in the command line while inside of the folder on the gnome file management. And as soon as I entered the command on the terminal, the file manager kicked me out of the mounted device, makes sense now! Thanks

Comment: Could you do us the favor and describe exactly that in the answer field below? That way, your question gets an answer (and thus doesn't show up as in need of answering anymore); and future searchers might just stumble across the same thing and be very thankful you did!

Answer (score 2):

Summarising the discussion in the comment section.

The problem is: every time you click the USB drive icon on the sidebar of the GNOME file manager to select the USB drive and open its content, the file manager checks if the device is mounted, and if it's not, it mounts again without letting you know.

Check it yourself: open the USB stick contents in the file manager and leave it open. Now in the terminal `umnount` the USB stick. You'll realise that you'll get kicked out of the file/directory in the file manager.

thanks @Marcus Müller for your help.